# Prove: $\Big|\dfrac{1}{x}\Big|=\dfrac{1}{|x|}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Can you help me to prove:
$$\Big|\dfrac{1}{x}\Big|=\dfrac{1}{|x|},$$ if $x\neq 0$.

I think the best way is recalling the definition of $|x|^{-1}$.

Comment: That sounds like an excellent plan. Thus: please recall the definition of $|x|^{-1}$.

Comment: Recall the definition of $|y|=\begin{cases}y &\text{if $y\geq 0$}\\ -y &\text{if $y<0$}\end{cases}$. By analyzing both cases separately you will get your proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1: $x>0$:

$$\left|\frac{1}{x}\right| = \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{|x|}$$

Case 2: $x<0$:

$$\left|\frac{1}{x}\right| = -\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{-x} = \frac{1}{|x|}$$

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides by |x| you will get the following:

$$|x|*|\frac{1}{x}| = 1$$

Now we can safely remove the absolute mark since we know that on the left side we will always have a positive number either $x$ is positive $(+ * + = +)$ or negative $(- * - = +)$ and now
on the left side is a multiplication of a number and it's reciprocal which always equals 1...

$$x*\frac{1}{x} = 1$$

$$Qed$$