# Prove: $\dfrac{|x|}{|y|}=\left|\dfrac{x}{y}\right|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Can you help me to prove that
$$\dfrac{|x|}{|y|}=\left|\dfrac{x}{y}\right|$$, if $y\neq 0$.

Comment: Well, do the four cases.

Comment: I see that you asked 3 separate questions based on the modulus property.  Maybe you should have posted all of them at once and asked if you had a specific query. What exactly is troubling you?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $|ab|=|a||b|$.
Then let $a=x$ and $b=1/x$ to get

$$1 = |x \cdot \frac{1}{x} | = |x| | \frac{1}{x}|$$

Rearrange to get $|\frac{1}{x}| = \frac{1}{|x|}$.

Now let $a=x$ and $b=1/y$. Then

$$\left| \frac{x}{y} \right| = \left| x \cdot \frac{1}{y} \right| = |x| \left| \frac{1}{y} \right| = |x| \frac{1}{|y|} = \frac{|x|}{|y|}.$$

It is up to you to show $|ab|=|a||b|$.

Answer (score 1):

It follows directly from [Prove: $\Big|\dfrac{1}{x}\Big|=\dfrac{1}{|x|}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917932/) and [Prove: $|xy|=|x|\cdot |y|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917860/)

$$\frac{|x|}{|y|}=\frac{1}{|y|}|x|=\left|\frac{1}{y}\right||x|=\left|\frac{x}{y}\right|,\quad y\neq 0$$